# How to fill out an abstract method?

Tags: swift

I'm using an SDK (AdColony) to show ads to the users. There is an abstract method in the AdColonyZone object.

Here is the header file: https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK/blob/master/AdColony.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/AdColony.framework/Headers/AdColonyZone.h

The reference to method I used (setReward) is on line 78:

```
- (void)setReward:(nullable void (^)(BOOL success, NSString *name, int amount))reward;
```

The documentation: https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK/wiki/Showing-Rewarded-Interstitial-Ads

The example code from the documentation:

```
let rewardedZones:Array<String> = [/* Rewarded Zone IDs */]
AdColony.configure(withAppID: /* App ID */, zoneIDs: /* Zone IDs */, options: nil) { [weak self] (zones) in
    for zone in zones {
        if rewardedZones.contains(zone.identifier) {
            zone?.setReward = { [weak self] (success, name, amount) in
                if success {
                    self?.rewardUser(coinsAmount: amount, currencyName: name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
AdColony.configure(withAppID: "MY_APP_ID", zoneIDs: ["MY_ZONE_ID"], options: nil){ (zones) in
    for zone in zones {
        zone.setReward = { (success, name, amount) in
            if success {
                // TODO: Something...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not able to set "setReward". I'm getting this error:

```
error: cannot assign to value: 'setReward' is a method
zone.setReward = { (success, name, amount) in
                    ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

How can I set the setReward handler?

Comment: Might not be the issue but it seems there is optional chaining on zone in this line `zone?.setReward` while your code does not do this `zone.setReward` so maybe do it the same way as the sdk - any difference ?

Comment: I get this error when I use it like that: error: cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type  'AdColonyZone'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AdColony.configure(withAppID: "MY_APP_ID", zoneIDs: ["MY_ZONE_ID"], options: nil){ (zones) in
    for zone in zones {
        zone.setReward { success, name, amount in
            if success {
                // TODO: Something...
            }
        }
    }
}
```